¿Cómo puedo hacer funcionar un filtro de fechas con input en PHP?
<?php 
require_once "../../dbconect.php";
// Obtener los valores del filtro de fechas
$fecha_inicio = isset($_GET['fecha_inicio']) ? $_GET['fecha_inicio'] : '';
$fecha_fin = isset($_GET['fecha_fin']) ? $_GET['fecha_fin'] : '';
// Consulta SQL para obtener los datos combinados de las tablas
$sql = "SELECT ma.pk_autonomo, a.pk_areas, m.pk_maquinas, a.nombre_areas, m.nombre_maquinas, ma.fecha, 
               COUNT(DISTINCT ma.fecha) AS total_dias_trabajados, 
               SUM(ma.tiempo_total) AS total_horas_trabajadas, 
               COUNT(ma.pk_autonomo) AS mantenimientos_autonomos_realizados, 
               1 AS indicador
        FROM (
            SELECT ma.pk_autonomo, ma.fecha, ma.tiempo_total, ma.fk_areas, ma.fk_maquinas
            FROM mant_autonomo ma
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ml.pk_autonomol AS pk_autonomo, ml.fecha, ml.tiempo_total, ml.fk_areas, ml.fk_maquinas
            FROM mant_autonomoliquidos ml
        ) AS ma
        INNER JOIN areas a ON ma.fk_areas = a.pk_areas
        INNER JOIN maquinas m ON ma.fk_maquinas = m.pk_maquinas
        LEFT JOIN reporte_autonomo ra ON ra.fk_maquina = ma.fk_maquinas 
                                     AND ra.fk_area = ma.fk_areas 
                                     AND ra.fecha = ma.fecha";
// Aplicar el filtro de fechas si están presentes
if ($fecha_inicio && $fecha_fin) {
    $sql .= " WHERE ma.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'";
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY ma.pk_autonomo, a.pk_areas, m.pk_maquinas, a.nombre_areas, m.nombre_maquinas, ma.fecha";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
// Verificar si hubo un error en la consulta
if (!$result) {
    echo "<p>Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($mysqli) . "</p>";
    exit;
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $fk_maquina = $row['pk_maquinas'];  
    $fk_area = $row['pk_areas'];       
    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
    $TDT = $row['total_dias_trabajados'];
    $THT = $row['total_horas_trabajadas'];
    $TMA = $row['mantenimientos_autonomos_realizados'];
    $indicador = $row['indicador'];
    // Verificar si el registro ya existe
    $check_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM reporte_autonomo 
                  WHERE fk_maquina = '$fk_maquina' 
                  AND fk_area = '$fk_area' 
                  AND fecha = '$fecha'";
    $check_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check_sql);
    $check_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_result);
    if ($check_row['count'] > 0) {
        // Si el registro existe, actualiza el registro
        $update_sql = "UPDATE reporte_autonomo 
                       SET TDT = '$TDT', THT = '$THT', TMA = '$TMA', Indicador = '$indicador'
                       WHERE fk_maquina = '$fk_maquina' 
                       AND fk_area = '$fk_area' 
                       AND fecha = '$fecha'";
        $update_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $update_sql);
        if (!$update_result) {
            echo "<p>Error al actualizar: " . mysqli_error($mysqli) . "</p>";
        }
    } else {
        // Si el registro no existe, inserta un nuevo registro
        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO reporte_autonomo (fk_maquina, fk_area, fecha, TDT, THT, TMA, Indicador)
                       VALUES ('$fk_maquina', '$fk_area', '$fecha', '$TDT', '$THT', '$TMA', '$indicador')";
        $insert_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insert_sql);
        if (!$insert_result) {
            echo "<p>Error al insertar: " . mysqli_error($mysqli) . "</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Reporte de Mantenimiento Autónomo</title>
    
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;  
            margin: 20px 0;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            font-weight: bold;      
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .filter-container {
            margin: 20px auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .filter-container input[type="date"] {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }
        .filter-container button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #dc3545;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .filter-container button:hover {
            background-color: #c82333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>REPORTE DE MANTENIMIENTO AUTÓNOMO</h1>
        <div class="filter-container">
            <form method="GET" action="">
                <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" value="<?php echo $fecha_inicio; ?>">
                <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" value="<?php echo $fecha_fin; ?>">
                <button type="submit">Filtrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <table id="iddatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
            <thead style="background-color: #dc3545; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Área</td>
                    <td>Equipo o Máquina</td>
                    <td>Fecha</td>
                    <td>Total Días Trabajados</td>
                    <td>Total Horas Trabajadas</td>
                    <td>Mant. Autónomos Realizados</td>
                    <td>Indicador (TMA-TDT)</td>
                    <td>Acciones</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot style="background-color: #ccc; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Área</td>
                    <td>Equipo o Máquina</td>
                    <td>Fecha</td>
                    <td>Total Días Trabajados</td>
                    <td>Total Horas Trabajadas</td>
                    <td>Mant. Autónomos Realizados</td>
                    <td>Indicador (TMA-TDT)</td>
                    <td>Acciones</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                // Mostrar los datos en la tabla
                mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); 
                while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['pk_autonomo']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre_areas']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre_maquinas']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['fecha']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['total_dias_trabajados']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['total_horas_trabajadas']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['mantenimientos_autonomos_realizados']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['indicador']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="EditarAutonomoFormulario.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar['pk_autonomo']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 25,
        responsive: true,
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'copy', title: 'ExampleFile' },
            { extend: 'csv', title: 'ExampleFile' },
            { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
            { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },
            { extend: 'print', 
              customize: function (win) {
                  $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                  $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                  $(win.document.body).find('table')
                      .addClass('compact')
                      .css('font-size', 'inherit');
              }
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Problema

El filtro de fechas no parece estar funcionando correctamente. Quiero que el usuario pueda seleccionar una fecha de inicio y una fecha de fin, y que los resultados se filtren de acuerdo a esas fechas.
Ejemplo de Entrada y Salida Esperada
Entrada: fecha_inicio = "2024-01-01", fecha_fin = "2024-01-31"
Salida Esperada: Resultados que muestren solo los registros dentro de ese rango de fechas.
Pregunta
¿Hay algo que falte en el código o alguna forma de mejorar la implementación del filtro para que funcione correctamente?

Hola. ¿Has hecho algún tipo de depuración? Por ejemplo, imprimir la instrucción SQL y en primer lugar revisar que es correcta desde el punto de vista sintáctico y en segundo lugar probarla en la base de datos. Sin saber la consulta que se está produciendo y la realidad de tus datos en la BD es imposible poder decirte si algo está mal aquí. Además, haces una segunda consulta dentro del while, ¿por qué? Es mejor hacer una consulta única... Ni siquiera dices en la pregunta si lo que falla es la primera consulta o la segunda ... o las dos.

Deberías usar sentencias preparadas. Tal y como está ahora el código es potencialmente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Sin ver todo el código te puedo decir: Mira lo que se recibe del formulario en cuanto a fechas, con esas fechas depura tu query. Pueda que a parte de las fechas 2024-09-15 necesites las horas 2024-09-15 00:00:01 a 2024-09-15 23:59:59

Es muy probable que estés teniendo un error de conversión de fecha a cadena y de regreso a fecha. El valor podría estar cambiando.  Lo ideal sería parametrizar la consulta en vez de concatenar valores.
